# Salesforce Marketing Cloud / Exacttarget SSJS HTTPGet Set Content Type

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I use SSJS to create a Image Content Block. However, I want to automate the whole process from getting image from URL using HTTP.get(url) and Insert into Content Builder. but I am getting strange characters from HTTP.get(url)
can I use something like this?

```
var reqHeaderNames = ["Content-Type"];

var reqHeaderValues = ["image/jpeg"];

var response = HTTP.Get(imgURL,reqHeaderNames,reqHeaderValues);
```

Do anyone know how I can use Automation Script Activity (SSJS) to get images from URLs and insert into Content Builder for email to use?

Comment: What strange char are you receiving? I believe it would return a Base64 encoded image (a bunch of seemingly random numbers/letters) - is that what you are seeing?

Comment: I got response from Salesforce support and product team that it is not supported.